# Как в discord.py узнать ID сервера?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global m
  with open("users.json", "r") as j:
    m = json.load()
    j.close()
  if len(m) == 0:
    m = {}
    for member in client.get_guild('id сервера').members:
```

Как можно узнать этот ID в discord.py?

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас я попытаюсь вам помочь.

Это можно сделать через `ctx.message.guild.id`! Вот пример кода:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['guildid', 'id'])
async def айди(ctx):
    await ctx.reply(f'Здравствуйте! Айди данного сервера: {ctx.message.guild.id}')
```

Вот как это будет выглядить в живую ((((извиняюсь за белую тему)))):
[image: извиняюсь за белую тему]

Вы можете как либо изменять данный код. Если нужна помощь, то пишите комментарий! Удачного дня

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать это так:

```
@bot.command('сервер-id')
async def getguildID(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.guild.id
    await ctx.channel.send(f'ID сервера : {id}')
```

Comment: мой ответ помог?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: тоесть как я понял ваш код узнаёт ID сервера?

Comment: @Шпеньков Кирилл да, и отправляет его. если это то, что нужно вам - поставьте галочку

Comment: мне именно нужно чтобы он не отправлял, а узнавал. А `id = ctx.message.guild.id` узнаёт ID канала или ID сервера? Тоесть я могу написать так: `for member in client.get_guild(id).members:`?

Comment: @ШпеньковКирилл узнает ID сервера